# Import JPMML to my Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, pmml

How to add jpmml (https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml) to my Android Studio project? I tried to use pom.xml file but it didn't help. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [the newer replacement](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml#important)? Beyond that, you do not need a `pom.xml` file, but to add dependencies based upon [their docs](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml#class-model-1). That would appear to be `compile 'org.jpmml:pmml-model:1.0.22'` and `compile 'org.jpmml:pmml-schema:1.0.22'`, if I am interpreting their instructions correctly.

Comment: No, I just haven't noticed that. I tried to add dependencies to this new version but it doesn't work to.

Comment: I put into gradle: compile 'org.jpmml:jpmml-model:1.2.11' and compile 'org.jpmml:jpmml-evaluator:1.2.12' and click Sync Project with Gradle Files and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [JPMML-Android](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android) project.